# Is there any fuse server/client software like sshfs but don't have any ssh authentication?

Tags: fuse, sshfs

I want to read log files in many linux hosts.

But don't have all the ssh permisson on all the hosts.

Instead, I can install a agent on all the hosts.

So, Is there any fuse server/client software like sshfs but don't have any ssh authentication?

Then I can mount all the log dir to one host, and easy to access them.

Comment: maybe should be migrated to unix.stackexchange

Comment: Latest `sshfs` versions provide a slave mode that allows one to use custom transport layers (instead of SSH). In some way you will have to connect `sshfs` to a `sftp-server` process running on the remote host.

Comment: A better alternative would be to have an user account in all the host configured to access the logs via SFTP exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

if it is about logs, you should instead configure `syslog` or any other logging facility you are using to send a copy of the logs directly to a remote machine.

Comment: in my environment, we don't need to send all logs to one machine, which cost time,cpu and net transport. It is just for developer occasionally find bugs from some logs.